# How to display the name of day for current date in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php

I want to print the name of the current date in laravel 5.3. I can get the current date in following ways:

```
     <?php use Carbon\Carbon;
$carbon=Carbon::now();
              echo $carbon->day;?>
```

The above code prints 25 but I want it to print Thursday.How should I do that??

Comment: try this   Carbon::now()->format('l');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Carbon get day name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782717/carbon-get-day-name)

Comment: check Answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782886/1969866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php use Carbon\Carbon;
$carbon=Carbon::now();
echo $carbon->format('l');?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

`Carbon::now()->format('l')` works but I would recommend using

`Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%A')`

seeing that this would translate the day string according to the current set locale in case your app is going support internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

After Laravel 5.5 you can use now() function to get the current date and time.

In blade file, you can write like this to print name of current day.

```
{{  now()->format('l') }}
```

[image]